# Derivative of convolution type integral equation with respect to time $ x(t) = \int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{t-s} u(s)ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification

**Consider the equation:**

$$x(t) = \int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{t-s} u(s)ds$$

where $x, u$ are functions and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

**I am trying to obtain the derivative of this equation with respect to time $t$**

*which is known to be* $$\dot x = u - \log(\frac{1}{\gamma})x$$

*(I am not sure if the $\log$ term is supposed to be a $\ln$ or $\log_\gamma(\cdot)$)*

**Attempt at derivation:**

$$x(t) = \int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{t-s} u(s)ds = \gamma^{t}\int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{-s} u(s)ds$$
$$\implies \log_\gamma(x(t)) = \log_\gamma(\gamma^{t}\int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{-s} u(s)ds) = t + \log_\gamma(\int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{-s} u(s)ds) $$
$$\implies \dfrac{\dot x(t)}{x(t)} = 1 + \dfrac{\gamma^{-t} u(t)}{\int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{-s} u(s)ds} $$
$$\implies \dfrac{\dot x(t)}{x(t)} = 1 + \dfrac{ u(t)}{\gamma^{t}\int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{-s} u(s)ds} $$

$$\implies \dot x(t) = x(t) + u(t) $$

> But I am not getting this mysterious $\log(\frac{1}{\gamma})$ term,
>   can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute (using the product derivation rule)
$$
\dot x(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\gamma^{t}\cdot\int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{-s} u(s)ds\right)=\log(\gamma)\, \gamma^t\cdot \int\limits_{0}^t \gamma^{-s} u(s) ds+\gamma^t\cdot\left(\gamma^{-t}u(t)\right)=\log(\gamma)\cdot x(t)+u(t).
$$